# Angular2+ - Combining 2 observables calls into one

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to combine both of these calls into one so they call async or subsequently. I'm thinking I have to use of, map or switchMap.

The imageType is an enum.

It should return as a string uri.

enum

```
export enum ImageType {
    Avatar = 1,
    Cover = 2
}
```

component.ts

```
this.service.getphotos(ImageType.Avatar, this.id).subscribe(result => {
    this.avatarPhotos = result;
});

this.service.getphotos(ImageType.Cover, this.id).subscribe(result => {
    this.coverPhotos = result;
});
```

service.ts

```
getPhotos(imageType: ImageType, id: number): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(`api/getphotos/${imageType}/${id}`);
    }
```

Comment: You can use [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest)

Comment: The answer will differ depending on what you want to happen if one of the calls fails. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Currently if an image is not available then I have a default image, which is implemented onError on the <IMG>. If one call fails then I'd like it to error (I removed the error for readability).

Comment: Thanks I'll look up combineLatest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution, is here:

```
combineLatest([
  this.service.getphotos(ImageType.Avatar, this.id).pipe(
    tap(result => (this.avatarPhotos = result)),
  ),
  this.service.getphotos(ImageType.Cover, this.id).pipe(
    tap(result => (this.coverPhotos = result)),
  )
]).subscribe()
```

You can do this with `forkJoin` either.

Comment: I think it should be 'tap(result=> (this.avatarPhotos = result)),' so please edit if it is. I've marked it as the correct answer. Thanks for the help. I'll be spending today on RxJs!

Comment: @Robgit28 Yeah, thanks!

Comment: Actually that's not good practice in example, only if property is not in a template. If it's in a template, - just use `async` pipe instead.